# Elementary OS wont start in Hyper-V even when Secure Boot is disabled

Tags: boot

Elementary OS wont start in Hyper-V even when Secure Boot is disabled. It gives out an error `error: out of memory.` And will not start. I just want to try it out in a VM to see what it's like. Don't want to do it on real hardware.

Comment: How much memory have you given the virtual machine? The minimum is 4GB on bare metal, and generally a little bit more when running as a virtual instance 

Comment: It's fine, all fixed now, for more information: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/13mtb45/comment/jl0f5jc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3